# After disabling caching in Rails, I am now seeing raw data in my page

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I'm not sure of how to describe this any better. I'm working through Agile Web Development with Rails 4 and just finished up with section 8.5, which describes how to cache pages. The problem is that, now that I've disabled caching, I'm stilling getting this output at the very bottom of my page:

```
[#<Product id: 6, title: "Product name", description: "Blah!", image_url: "blah.jpg", price: #<BigDecimal:7fb3b6a331f0,'0.35E2',9(36)>, created_at: "2013-12-22 02:38:57", updated_at: "2013-12-22 02:38:57">, #<Product id: 4, title: "Whatever Fest", description: "Awesome!", image_url: "highlandfest.jpg", price: #<BigDecimal:7fb3b6a323e0,'0.4995E2',18(45)>, created_at: "2013-12-19 05:20:29", updated_at: "2013-12-19 05:22:04">, #<Product id: 7, title: "Nell Park", description: "Northeast", image_url: "what.jpg", price: #<BigDecimal:7fb3b6a316e8,'0.3E2',9(36)>, created_at: "2013-12-22 02:40:41", updated_at: "2013-12-22 02:40:41">, #<Product id: 8, title: "Blah Blah Shoeface", description: "Southwest", image_url: "shoe_face.jpg", price: #<BigDecimal:7fb3b6a309f0,'0.3E2',9(36)>, created_at: "2013-12-22 02:41:35", updated_at: "2013-12-22 02:46:11">, #<Product id: 3, title: "Blah blah blah", description: "This one hits <em>pretty</em> close to home.", image_url: "adssadf.jpg", price: #<BigDecimal:7fb3b6a39780,'0.1E-1',9(45)>, created_at: "2013-12-19 03:21:26", updated_at: "2013-12-19 09:20:38">]
```

Removing this fixes the issue, but it's not clear what's happening here.

```
<%= cache ['store', Product.latest] do %>
    <%= @products.each do |product| %>  

    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Could someone help me understand what's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't have anything to do with caching.  The explanation of what you're seeing is as follows:

(1) In Ruby, all statements have return values.

(2) The return value of `each` is the enumerable object on which it's called.  In your example, that's `@products`, i.e., an array of Product instances.

(3) ERB elements with the `%=` tag cause the return value of the Ruby they contain to be (converted to a string and) inserted into the resulting HTML.

When you want to execute code in a view template but not display its return value, use `%` instead of `%=`.  In this case, both the `cache` and `@products.each` elements should use `%`.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the "=" in the erb, that is only for things you want to display.